# Cannot edit crontab

Tags: rhel, cron

I'm running RHEL 5.6. I type

```
$ crontab -e
```

and all I see is

```
Killed
```

I am, however, able to edit a file (let's say I call it crontab.in) and then type

```
$ crontab crontab.in
$ crontab -l
```

and see that it works that way and the entry I placed in `crontab.in` will run when it should.

So why is `crontab -e` not working for me?

Comment: Does `crontab -l` work? What's `$EDITOR` set to?

Comment: the editor needed a tmp file in /tmp dir may be permission question? and also do you start cronotab as sudoer $ or as root # ?

Comment: crontab -l does work (as I indicated). I did try setting EDITOR. I have permissions to /tmp (touch /tmp/foo works for example). I do not have root privs on the server, so I do not start crond myself. It is, however, running as root.

Comment: I don't know, but personally I prefer `crontab <filename>` anyway; it avoids losing information if I make a mistake while editing. (I keep my crontab in a version control system.)

Comment: What exactly is `$EDITOR` set to? Do you have free space in `/tmp` (try `df /tmp`)?

Comment: This could fail if you aren't allowed to run cron jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strace` to find out what is going on.

Instead of `crontab -e` type `strace crontab -e`. That should give a (quite long) list all system calls of the running command. Near the end you should find some kind of error indicating what is wrong. (Often it is an open of a file on which you don't have the needed permissions.)

Comment: Looks like I cannot write to my own crontab in /var/spool/cron.

Comment: Oh, this is because of strace itself. Your crontab file is only accessible by root. Therefore the `crontab` binary is SUID, i.e. runs with root as effective user id. Now when strace starts the binary is is not possible to set the uid and you will not be able to access your file. - Seems like strace will not help you in your case.