# Cannot edit crontab from service

Tags: permissions, cron, root, services

I'd like to schedule a daily autoshutdown via `sudo service autoshutdown start` or either abort it via `sudo service autoshutdown stop`.

#### /etc/systemd/system/autoshutdown.service

```
[Unit]
Description=AutoShutdown
[Service]
User = root
Type = oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/autoshutdown.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/crontab -r
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### /etc/systemd/system/autoshutdown.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "scheduling a shutdown 19:00..."
whoami
crontab -l | cat - /etc/systemd/system/autoshutdown.txt > crontab.txt && crontab crontab.txt
echo "crontab is now"
crontab -l
```

#### /etc/systemd/system/autoshutdown.txt

```
50 18 * * * /sbin/shutdown +10
```

All amazing. So `start`ing service runs correctly, and when `status`ing service, I see

> [omissis] autoshutdown.sh[11178]: scheduling a shutdown 19:00...
>
> [omissis] autoshutdown.sh[11178]: root
>
> [omissis] autoshutdown.sh[11178]: 50 18 * * * /sbin/shutdown +10

So everything seems ok. However, a latter `sudo crontab -l` returns an empty table.

"Where" did my crontab go?

Possibly [un]related questions:

1. [Cannot edit crontab as non root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148123/cannot-edit-crontab-as-non-root-user)
2. [Cannot edit crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61787/cannot-edit-crontab)

Comment: Does `crontab.txt` contain what you would expect?

Comment: Just refined its absolute path to `/etc/systemd/system/crontab.txt` and yes, its content is equal to `/etc/systemd/system/autoshutdown.txt` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for the required behaviour, the most fitting option is `RemainAfterExit=yes` (default: no).

Otherwise, once `ExecStart` end, `ExecStop` is immediately executed.

Source: [FreeDesktop Systemd Manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)